# Google place text search api not working with location

Tags: android, ios, google-places

I am using the below API and that need to give me the result of India only as I pass India location but it gives me USA address.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=asd&location=23.012509,72.522761&radius=5000&key=AIzaSyBSomSDu5wlDiL6sAngHy-zaPXH4-Y_cyw

Comment: use this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=asd&location=23.012509,72.522761&radius=5000&key=AIzaSyBSomSDu5wlDiL6sAngHy-zaPXH4-Y_cyw&region=IN

Comment: set region will help you..

Comment: But keyword "asd" has no location so result should be zero and here can find one result so its not true. and I am in ahmedabad an I set radius to 5000 meter so its not need to take Gandhinagar

Comment: This happened to me as well. I needed to update the `input` search parameter (used in Places `findplacebytext` search) to `query` (used in Places `textsearch` search)